# How to reference CLR UDTs when creating a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have no idea why there is very little documentation on this so I'll ask here.

I have created some user defined data types and would like to use them when creating a table.
However I have no idea what the syntax is for calling to them.

Yes I know it's best to STAY AWAY from them but I'm in a position where I am forced to work with them.

Comment: Are you talking about [CLR UDTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx) or are you talking about [user-defined data types (alias types)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189283(v=sql.105).aspx), formerly known as UDTs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use User Defined Types (UDTs) just like the built-in types.

- [Defining UDT Tables and Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131076.aspx)

> **There is no special syntax for creating a UDT column in a table. You
>   can use the name of the UDT in a column definition as though it were
>   one of the intrinsic SQL Server data types.**
>
> The following CREATE TABLE Transact-SQL statement creates a table
>   named Points, with a column named ID, which is defined as an int
>   identity column and \ the primary key for the table. The second column
>   is named PointValue, with a data type of Point. The schema name used
>   in this example is dbo. Note that you must have the necessary
>   permissions to specify a schema name. If you omit the schema name, the
>   default schema for the database user is used.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.Points 
> (
>     ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
>     PointValue Point
> )
> ```

- [Registering User-Defined Types in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131079.aspx)

Comment: Hmm maybe im missing something other than creating the UDT is there another step in between...

Comment: it works now i dont know whats up with sql server i had to restart it and it finally took note of my UDTs